# Changing base_urls to work on localhost

Tags: configuration, nginx, base-url, localhost, core-config-data

I have some databases which we use for our staging servers to test changes to code, and I want to import them and use them locally.

I've managed to import the database fine, but my admin panel is still linking to the staging servers instead of locally. I'd like to change the base_urls in core_config_data so that I can use the admin panel locally.

So far I've done this:
[image]
Changing the base_urls to point to my localhost. But this seems to have given me 504 gateway timeouts.

I'm running nginx and php7.0-fpm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure all instances are covered you could run the query

```
UPDATE core_config_data 
SET value = 'http://127.0.0.1/' 
WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url');
```

Delete in CLI var/cache and then run: cache:clean and cache:flush

If that doesn't work, edit your local hosts file to add

172.27.0.1 test.testingserver.com
127.0.0.1 test.testingserver.com

and change your urls on to test.testingserver.com

I have no idea why I sometimes have to add the 172.27.0.1 but I read it once and it seems to work when everything else is failing.

Comment: Is it wrong for me to be using https for the secure base urls instead of http? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I've changed it to http and it's no longer giving me a 504 error which is nice, but it doesn't login, just refreshes the admin page even though my credentials are correct (if i enter wrong credentials it tells me wrong password which is how I know)

Comment: I actually use http for secure and unsecure but ONLY for local testing. In live or dev testing servers I only use https.

Comment: It's really best to use your machine's local host file and use a domain like test.testingserver.com - it's more like a live environment and you don't have as many issues. I've never had good luck with magento using localhost or https://127.0.0.1/